# Anime creature with many trumpets on its side. Mid 80's

Tags: story-identification, anime, animation

I remember this mid 80's cartoon movie, I think anime.

A human child is nurtured by two fictional animal like creatures, perhaps on a spaceship. I remember one of them having funny trumpet-like organs on his sides. Maybe a phoenix is also involved in the plot?

I think the child had white complexion. The creature with trumpets appears purple in my memories. The scene that hit me was this creature making music with these many holes on his side to cheer up the baby. One of the creatures might have resembled a dinosaur...

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details? Every little bit helps us.

Comment: @Valorum  Thank you. I think the child had white complexion. The creature with trumpets appears purple in my memories. The scene that hit me was this creature making music with these many holes on his side to cheer up the baby. One of the creatures might have resembled  dinosaur.... although not sure.

Comment: @Manticore Where did you see this movie (tv, etc)? What language did you see this movie in? Did you see this movie in the 80's, or did you think it was created in the 80's?

Comment: @n_b I saw this at movie theater in the 80's, at around 1983-85. I was too young to recognize the language of it. However I remained with the feeling that is was an Asian creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Manticore's link, it looks like the film is *[Phoenix 2772](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_2772)*, a 1980 science fiction animation from Japan, written by Osamu Tezuka:

[image: Phoenix 2772 poster]

> *Phoenix 2772* is set in the distant future where the planet Earth is dying from a lack of energy resources and a disheartening political climate sees all human beings produced by computers to live out certain social roles, the colour of the eyes determining the baby's rank, from pilot to politician, etc. Godo is one such child brought up to be a cadet and nursed by the beautiful robot-maid Olga. After noticing his exceptional abilities, Rock, a dictatorial candidate for prime minister, selects Godo to fulfil his agenda and travel into deep space and capture the mystical Phoenix, its blood will manifestly heal the Earth (and selfishly make Rock prime minister). This eventually proves hard for Godo for many reasons, partly because he has a love of all living creatures and he detests his being trained for what appears to be that of a ruthless hunter. He is also to leave his one friend in his adolescence, Olga, to deletion. Most importantly he elopes with Rena, a "daughter of the elite" and bride-to-be of Rock when it is forbidden for his rank to communicate with such a woman.

While Gado's robot maid, Olga, is pretty human, the phoenix may be what you're thinking of. It has some trailing peacock-like feathers which do look sort of trumpet-like, and are purple in the episode, albeit orangeish on the VHS box cover:
[image: Phoenix 2772 VHS box cover]

Although there are a fair number of other aliens that show up:
[image: Godo, Olga, Pincho, and two other aliens]   [image: Other assorted aliens]

Here is a trailer:

Comment: My edits were getting extensive enough that I instead made this my own answer. Manticore, feel free to take whatever you would like from it.

Comment: Thank you FuzzyBoots, for the pcs and trailer. As you can see on the images posted There Is a creature with trumpet-like features on its sides, that he uses for making noise and sounds with (i.e. music, snorking). This creature had the biggest impact on me. As for the rest it is a good example of the footprint the movie left on a 4 years old's mind. I was amused myself.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the movie is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_2772